# How to have your own partition key while writing data in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using below code to write my content in Cosmos Db, however in Cosmos Db I see the Partition Key is automatically generated and it is for Id which I have kept as default. My requirement is to have my Own Partition Key . from my below json I would like TypeId to be my partition Key How can I do that in my below code?

**content** is of **JObject** Type and is of below format {{

```
"Classes": {
    "Subjects": {
      "Name": "testA",
      "TypeId": "AS88QW",
      "Public": "No"
    },
    "Sections": {
      "Scopes": true
    }
  }
```

C# code:

```
// initialized database settings and read json file as string....
 var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( lines );

            var client = new DocumentClient( new Uri(Instance ), Key );
            await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                Database, Collection ),
                content);   
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the container, you can specify the partition key which is path to a property in your JSON document. My guess is that when you (or someone else) created the container, `/id` was chosen as the partition key.

Considering partition key for a container can't be changed, what you need to do is create a new container. When you create the new container, ensure that the partition key property is set as `/Classes/Subjects/TypeId`.

Comment: one more thing if you don't mind, how can I avoid to enter duplicate items in cosmos db. if I am providing the same json lines in above code,multiple enteries are formed in Cosmos Db whereas I want a single entry

Comment: Please take a look at `Unique Key Constraints` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can form a partition key by concatenating multiple property values into a single artificial partitionKey property.

Please follow the steps given in below page:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-partitioning-and-partition-key-in-azure-cosmos-db/

Comment: FYI this isn't an "artificial" partition key. Combining multiple properties would be a *synthetic* key. Nothing artificial about it. Aside from that: the OP doesn't need something like that. They only need a path to a specific property within their document, as the other answer shows.