# Handling duplicate data in Cosmos Db

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Below is the code by which I am adding my json document in Cosmos Db. My Partition Key here is TypeId and combination of TypeId and CValue creates a unique value. Now below code is able to add document in my cosmosDb but it allows duplicate items to be added as well, which I would like to avoid and would like to know how can I handle this? Whenever a new document is added, it checks if the document with same unique key(TypeId and CValue) is present or not, and if present, either it overrides or don't add it.

```
var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( lines );
var client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( DbInstance ),Key );
await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                Database, Collection ),
                content);
```

content is a JObject and here is sample output of content :

```
"Classes": {
    "Subjects": {
      "Name": "testA",
      "TypeId": "AS88QW",
      "Public": "No"
    },
    "Sections": {
      "Scopes": true,
      "CValue": [12,12,1]
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can create a unique key when creating your container. Have you looked into that yet?

Comment: Based on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67984787/how-to-have-your-own-partition-key-while-writing-data-in-cosmos-db), I'm assuming the partition key for your container is `Classes/Subjects/TypeId`. Correct?

Comment: I looked into it but there is no code as such create unique key. you are right regarding partition key

Comment: Unique key constraint is defined as part of your container creation i.e. you define unique key constraints when you're creating container.

Comment: here i need combination of two key as unique key

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint - if you need to combine two separate properties to form a unique key, you'll need to create a synthetic key as the combination of those properties, and then specify the key as unique. Try this via the portal (setting up a unique key) to see if it gives you the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: You can use the combination of your partition key and id to make a unique value as well.

Comment: @Mark Brown.. how? my two key are TypeID and Cvalue which I need to combine and CValue is of type array

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Is there any progress sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed David's idea and execute the test, but it failed, pls allow me to show my test result below for the following discussion.

When we create a container, we can set unique keys, in your case, you can enter `Classes/Subjects/TypeId,Classes/Sections/CValue` in the field.

But per my testing, it can't make effect on type array. How about turning `CValue` into a string?

[image]

==================Update=======================

Creating Synthetic key, refer to [this sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3)

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://yourcosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/", "cosmosdb_primary_key_here");
            Container container = await client.GetDatabase("database_name").DefineContainer(name: "container_name", partitionKeyPath: "/ptk")
                .WithUniqueKey()
                .Path("/combinedProperity_set_to_be_unique_key")
                .Attach()
                .CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            var lines = "{\"id\":\"001\",\"TypeId\": \"AS88QW\",\"CValue\":[12,12,1]}";
            JObject content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(lines);
            string TypeId = content.GetValue("TypeId").ToString();
            string CValue = content.GetValue("CValue").ToString();
            content.Add(new JProperty("combinedProperty", TypeId+"-"+ CValue));
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            ItemResponse<JObject> createResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync(content);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Synthetic key]

Comment: but how do I do that in my code? I dont want to change the type of Cvalue, it can be allowed for creating unique key but cant change the initial structure of json

Comment: Pls note [unique key can only be created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys#define-a-unique-key) when you create the container. And in .net SDK, you can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-define-unique-keys?tabs=dotnetv3#use-the-net-sdk).

Comment: that we know.. we are facing the challenge where a key is of type array and it is not allowed to use this key as unique key. Unique key only support keys of type string number and bool

Comment: That's decided by the database, what we can do is try a flexible change to meet your requirement, and that's what your newly created question mentioned, using Synthetic key, according to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys#concatenate-multiple-properties-of-an-item), we can combine values of `TypeId` and `CValue` like `AS88QW-[12,12,1]`, and set this properity as the partion key. Like https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeEec.png

Comment: thats right..but i couldnt find any code sample implementing that

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint As David answered in your another question, you can combine that 2 values into one string manually. And , I think I need to find a sample for you...